# How can I prevent yum update from creating config files?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, yum, configuration

Occasionally when I run a `yum update`, some configuration files I deleted (or moved to another directory) are recreated. These seem to be the default configurations provided by the software.

Some examples are `httpd` and `yum`. This usually ends up breaking or altering my desired behavior.

In more detail for `yum`:

- under `/etc/yum.repo.d/` I've moved the files `*.repo` to `/etc/yum.repo.d/disabled`.
- after (a recent) `yum update` the default configuration files `CentOS-*.repo` are re-created under `/etc/yum.repo.d/`
- the next `yum update` will update from the default yum repositories, which is what I was trying to prevent in the first place.

Is the only way to prevent this to leave the files in the directory but wipe out the content? I'm worried it could do this with some new configuration.

Comment: Just never remove the files in the first place; comment out the conflicting configuration and any new package will (*should*) install its configuration in parallel.

Comment: I have to manage multiple servers though, and automate patching through my own repository.  It would be a pain to comment out configurations on every server so was hoping there would be an easier method.

Answer (score 1):

`yum` will preserve a customized configuration file as long as the file resides in its standard directory.

If the configuration update is a major one that obsoletes your customized one, then your current configuration is renamed with the suffix `.rpmsave` and the new, updated configuration is installed.

If the configuration update simply brings enhancements and/or minor changes, then your current configuration is left undisturbed, and the new configuration file is renamed with the suffix `.rpmnew`.

Thus, following a `yum update`, simply `find` files named `*.rpmnew` or `*.rpmsave` and compare and adjust as needed.

Comment: Sorry, 'replaced' was probably a bad word to use.  I meant 'recreated'.

Answer (score 0):

From your given scenario, as far as I understand and know from past experiences, an update or upgrade will also recreate (the default) configuration files.

In your case it will be necessary to implement some kind of configuration management. This can be additional scripts, tools or even more advanced infrastructure.